# Angular2 app deployed in Liferay stuck at "Loading..." with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, liferay, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to deploy my Angular IO app to Liferay platform with variable success. Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome render the Liferay portlet without any troubles, but [Internet Explorer 11 fails at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBr5T.jpg). To make matters even more bizarre, the app works fine with IE11 [on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUOlG.jpg) meaning that the polyfills.ts is working as expected.

**EDIT:** By studying the debugger a bit more on IE11 I found out that none of the js bundles generated by Angular are loaded. GET on main.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js and inline.bundle.js results in 404 Not Found.

**EDIT2:** The 404 happens because Exploder's request URL for GET is blatantly wrong. The correct syntax for URL is `http://host/portlet/app/*.bundle.js`, in Internet Explorer 11 the request URL is `http://host/web/guest/page/portlet/app/*.bundle.js`.

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: Only warnings as seen in the first picture.

Comment: at least work on the warnings you see: A document with multiple `<html>`, `<body>` etc *is* illegal and you can't blame a browser for not rendering it to your expectation. Liferay takes care of this part of the markup, meaning that your angular (or your portlet's) content *must not* contain this markup

Comment: Do you mean I should remove most if not all doctype, <head> and <body> declarations from my project? Why are Chrome, Edge and Firefox able to render the content without these warnings?

Comment: Well, a browser is free to *warn* about what it wants. And it's free to not render illegal content. I'm not saying that this is your solution, but if there's a warning, follow those signs first, then worry about more advanced stuff

Comment: I missed your Edits when I wrote the previous comment on my phone. You might want to give some details on how you construct the URLs that IE interprets wrong. Plus, am I right that you're using Liferay 6.2? That's also worth noting.

Comment: Thank you @OlafKock for bearing with me!

As I edited, I managed to pinpoint the problem to how the GET URL is formed and by trial and error (at first different `<base href="/">` combinations) I noticed that my .jsp file in charge of initiating the script loading was lacking a single `/`. I then modified the .jsp as follows:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="portlet/*.bundle.js"></script>`

=> changed to =>

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/portlet/*.bundle.js"></script>`.

Now everything seems to be working on IE11 aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the GET URL for scripts was malformed in Internet Explorer (EDITs of the original question. @OlafKock hinted to inspect how the GET URL is formed so I found out that my index.jsp file that's in charge of downloading the *bundle.js files, was lacking a single / character.

I then proceeded to apply the following fix:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="portlet/*.bundle.js"></script>`

=>
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/portlet/*.bundle.js"></script>`

Now everything works also on Internet Explorer 11.